# How to retrieve a form's validator

Tags: jquery-validate

What is the correct way to get the current jQuery validator object for an existing form?

Note, the validator is being configured using the jQuery Unobtrusive validation plugin hence why I don't have a reference to it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want:

```
var validator = $("#form_id").data("validator");
```

Comment: Returns undefined.

Comment: This is not documented. See below

Comment: If wanna call a function, you can make directly `$("#form_id").data("validator").resetForm()`

Comment: To validate the selected form:
`$("#form_id").data("validator").form();`

Answer (score 8):

From [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-validator):

> The **validate** method returns a Validator object

Next code will gets existing validator or init it

```
var validator = $("form_selector").validate();
```

Comment: Just to make it very clear: If the validator was already initialized, then this will return the *existing* instance without any re-initialization and any options passed will be completely ignored.